# Cordova Overscroll with Fixed Navbar and Toolbar

Tags: cordova, overscroll

I'd like to use overscroll functionality that comes with mobile apps, but I need to keep navbar and toolbar fixed.
 I keep

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
```

and I use https://framework7.io/ for building interfaces.

Any suggestions how can I keep navbar and toolbar fixed, with overscroll for other content?

Comment: Use pull to refresh: https://framework7.io/docs/pull-to-refresh.html

Comment: I already do but unfortunately this solution is not clean especially if you have tabs